# get_cog doesn't return loaded cog but None instead

Tags: python, discord.py

In my bot, I have a command that just prints out the names (and later descriptions as well) of all loaded cogs.
For most of them, it works perfectly fine, but it seems to have an issue with one named `RNG`

```py
for c in bot.cogs:
    if c is None:
        continue
    else:
        cog_list.append(c)
cog_list = sorted(cog_list)
print(cog_list)
>>> ['General', 'Misc', 'RNG']`  # (all loaded cogs, so this is correct)
for cog in cog_list:
    cog = bot.get_cog(cog.title())
    print(cog)
    >>> <general.General object at [...]>  # 'General' cog
    >>> <misc.Misc object at [...]>        # 'Misc' cog
    >>> None                               # 'RNG' cog, but it's not found? 
                                           # (expected <rng.RNG object at [...]>)
```

Just to show that the RNG cog is actually loaded, this is the output of `print(bot.cogs)`:

```
{'General': <general.General object at [...]>, 'Misc': <misc.Misc object at [...]>, 'RNG': <rng.RNG object at [...]>}
```

I know from the docs that `None` is returned when the cog is not found, but as I can clearly see, the RNG cog is very much loaded and the contained commands are working fine.

Now I wonder if it might be the name, but doing `help RNG` to the bot works perfectly fine as well.

Is there a way to make `get_cog` find my RNG module?

Comment: ```bot.cogs```  returns you a dict of objects, which contains the ```RNG``` module too, why don't you use that directly rather than trying to fetch the cog (using the name) again? This approach would make your code more robust as well.

Comment: I didn't realize I could directly use it this way, but I also wanted the module names to get sorted alphabetically and went with this roundabout way that I am familiar with already.
But you're absolutely right, directly using `bot.cogs` makes a lot more sense! 
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more descriptive naming can help you see what's going on

```
for cog_name in cog_list:
    print(cog_name.title())
```

prints

```
General
Misc
Rng
```

Note that `RNG` has become `Rng`.  This is because the `.title()` string method is making the string Title Case, where every word is capitalized. So in your search, you're looking up `Rng` and expecting it to find `RNG`, which doesn't work because the search is case sensitive.

Comment: I don't remember why I put title() in there... Obviously that would clash with case sensitive searching!
Thank you for pointing that out!